# what does this category in intent filter mean?

Tags: android, android-intent, categories

I always don't get what does category really do in the intent filter, especially in this case.

```
       <intent-filter>

            <!-- Receives the actual messages. -->
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <!-- Receives the registration id. -->
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

            <category android:name="com.androidhive.pushnotifications" />
        </intent-filter>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The point of the `<category>` is to filter incoming GCM notifications based on your app / package name.

The docs for GCM show `<category android:name="my_app_package" />` and as you have to register specific apps to allow GCM, this makes sense.

If you think about it, there may be any number of apps on an Android device which are registered for GCM. The fact they will all be receiving messages using the same core software means there has to be some way to 'route' the messages to the correct app - if there wasn't a way to do this, all GCM-registered apps would receive each others' messages.

Answer (score 1):

Those are intents used by the [Google Cloud Messaging](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/gs.html) service. See the topic ["Writing the Android Application"](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/gs.html#android-app) in the CGM Getting Started guide for info on these filters. Here's the main info (especially the last part):

> This broadcast receiver is responsible for handling the 2 intents that can be sent by GCM (`com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE` and `com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION`) and should be defined in the manifest (rather than programmatically) so that these intents can be received even if the application is not running. By setting the `com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND` permission, you are ensuring that only intents sent by the GCM system framework are sent to the receiver (a regular application cannot issue intents with that permission).
>
> Notice that android:name in the category tag must be replaced by your application's package name (and the category tag is not required for applications targeted to minSdkVersion 16 and higher).

Comment: This does not answer his question about IntentFilter categories.

Comment: @tolgap - Good point. I added the relevant part of the docs regarding how to use the intent category.

Comment: still didnt get it, what's the category for??

Comment: @Blake - Categories help further restrict the activities that will match an intent. This is described in the topic [Intents and Intent Filters](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html). Basically, a category is: _"A string containing additional information about the kind of component that should handle the intent."_ The [IntentFilter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/IntentFilter.html) rule for categories is: _"Categories match if all of the categories in the Intent match categories given in the filter."_